# Fizz Buzz script using while loop stuck in infinite loop - php

Tags: php, while-loop, fizzbuzz

I'm trying to write a Fizz Buzz script using a `while` loop to cycle through the numbers `1-100` and `echo` each one to the screen.

I'm using the modulus operator to find if a number is a multiple of:

- 3 in which case it echos Fizz,
- 5 in which case it echos Buzz,
- or if its a multiple of both 3 and 5 it echos FizzBuzz

I've written the code below, tested all its parts and it seems to work, but when I run the script, it gets stuck in an infinite loop, echoing `Fizz`.

```
$i = 1;

while ($i <= 100) {

    if ((3 % $i) === 0) {
        echo 'Fizz';
        $i = $i++;
    } else if ((5 % $i) === 0) {    
        $i = $i++;
        echo 'Buzz';        
    } else if ( ((3 % $i) === 0) && ((5 % $i) === 0)){
        echo 'FizzBuzz';
    } else {
        echo $i++;
    }

}
```

Any idea were I went wrong?

Comment: `$i % 3`. And you don't need the third and the fourth conditions

Comment: Should this be tagged [tag:homework]?

Comment: @cbuckley: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated

Comment: "My code doesn't work, where is the bug" style questions are seen as off topic. What have you tried? Where specifically are you stuck? What don't you understand. If you can distill that out, it will make both your experience and the overall communities experience better. But as it stands this question could use some improvement...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$i = 1;

while ($i <= 100) {

    $r = '';

    if ($i % 3 === 0) {
        $r .= 'Fizz';
    }

    if ($i % 5 === 0) {    
        $r .= 'Buzz';        
    }

    if (!$r) {
        $r = $i;
    }

    echo "$r\n";
    ++$i;
}
```

Online demo: http://ideone.com/WbXZEd

Comment: Can you **please** put some explanation into this answer? I know code-only answers are allowed, but come on. Who is this really helping?

Comment: @ircmaxel: this answer contains only trivial operators and constructions. If OP cannot recognize any particular one - I'd be happy to explain one. But I won't explain what `=` and `<=` do - there is php manual for that.

Comment: The prints incorrect result -- no numbers. Check this wiki http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FizzBuzzTest

Comment: @omarithawi it produces the correct result. Please check the link provided in the answer. Thank you.

Comment: @zerkms Sure, I did! Check **[this screenshot](http://oi57.tinypic.com/idg5j8.jpg)** your provided link it starts with `Fizz,Buzz`. While the **[correct FizzBuzz](http://ideone.com/dKqwzs)** starts with `1,2,Fizz,4,Buzz...`. Thank you